# Chroma db not working in both persistent and http client modes

Tags: langchain, chromadb

I am trying to use chroma vector store in Python but I cannot make it work.

When I tried to create a persistent client using the command below I got the below error.

`client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=path="/path/to/save/to")`

ERROR:
`RuntimeError: Chroma is running in http-only client mode, and can only be run with 'chromadb.api.fastapi.FastAPI' as the chroma_api_impl.             see https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide?lang=py#using-the-python-http-only-client for more information.`

I also tried to run chroma in http-only client mode. I used the code below:

`from chromadb import HttpClient`

`from chromadb.config import Settings`

`settings = Settings(chroma_api_impl="chromadb.api.fastapi.FastAPI", allow_reset=True, anonymized_telemetry=False)`

`client = HttpClient(host='localhost',port=8000,settings=settings)`

it worked but when I tried to create a collection I got the following error:

ERROR:
`ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

Any help would be truly appreciated :).

Many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a local **non-persistent** (data gone after execution finished) Chroma database, you can do

```py
# embedding model as example
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# load it into Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function)
```

If you want to create/ load from a local **persistent** Chroma vectorstore,

```py
# save to disk
db2 = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function,
                            persist_directory="./chroma_db")
docs = db2.similarity_search(query)

# load from disk
db3 = Chroma(persist_directory="./chroma_db", embedding_function=embedding_function)
docs = db3.similarity_search(query)
print(docs[0].page_content)
```

If you want to pass a Chroma client into LangChain, you would have to have a standalone Chroma vectorstore engine running over HTTP.

Here's the reference doc > https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/chroma

Comment: Many thanks! But when I tried your suggestion I got the below error:

ERROR: RuntimeError: Chroma is running in http-only client mode, and can only be run with 'chromadb.api.fastapi.FastAPI' as the chroma_api_impl.             see https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide?lang=py#using-the-python-http-only-client for more information.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: this answer works locally but I think OP wanted to get it running over http. I also arrived at this QA for that reason. Anyway, the reference doc link is helpful, but you may want to quote the relevant parts from the docs into your answer as link rot is very likely for these fast evolving libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the simple code and please give a try

```py
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings

# using open source llm and download to local disk
embedding_function = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name="sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2")

# use `from_texts` instead of `from_documents`, for reference
vectorstore = Chroma.from_texts(["harry potter's owl is in the castle."], 
                        embedding_function, persist_directory="./chroma_db")
query = "where is Harry Potter's Hedwig?"
docs = vectorstore.similarity_search(query)
print(docs[0].page_content)
```